# Euler Angle Notation

Tags: mathematics, terminology

**Fundamental Question**

Correct me if I am wrong here. For Euler Rotations, we use the right hand rule. So a positive rotation in X-Axis will represent a clockwise rotation; whereas a positive rotation in the Y-Axis will represent a clockwise rotation as well.

Why is a counter-clockwise rotation in the Z-Axis (thumb) represented as a positive rotation?

Is it because we are trying to say a counter-clockwise Z rotation is trying to bring +x towards +Y? Can we think it that way?

Comment: in what way do you think positive rotations about X and Y are clockwise?  if you take the axis as out of the clock face, all positive right-hand-rule rotations are counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 7):

All rotations in an Euler sequence (whether about the x, y, or z axes) are counterclockwise in the sense of the right hand thumb rule. Orient the thumb of your right hand in the direction of the positive axis in question. Your remaining four fingers on your right hand curl in the direction of positive rotation about that axis.

Comment: I am 82 years old and can still find my right hand.  Pointing that RH thumb up shows my fingers in a CCW position.  "Just for a little humor here."